# Opening a URL in the AndroidTV emulator does not work, works fine on my AndroidTV box

Tags: android-emulator, android-tv

I have made a small AndroidTV app that can query a rest api and present the content that it returns. This works without any issues when I am running the app on my Nexus Player with AndroidTV 7 (API 25).

To be able to work on the app, when I'm commuting I would like to be able to develop using the AndroidTV emulator. But when I run my app in the emulator I cannot access my api endpoints.

The emulator does have internet connectivity. In the AndroidTV emulator the "Videos" leanback sample is pre-installed. And that can access the internet and fetch the images from their endpoints.

The code I'm using currently looks like this:

```
final URL url1;
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
try {
    url1 = new URL(url);
    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url1.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setUseCaches(true);
    urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "only-if-cached");
    int maxStale = 60 * 60 * 10; // tolerate stale time in seconds
    urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "max-stale=" + maxStale);
    return urlConnection.getInputStream();
} finally {...}
```

If I use the Google Videos sample resource URL's as input to the above code, I am able to fetch their resources, also when run in the emulator. 
Requesting data from my own rest endpoint (also publicly available on the internet) gives a FileNotFoundException.

The urls that cause the exception can be access from my host machine without any problems.

One of the sample resources from the Videos leanback sample is this one:
http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/android-tv/Sample%20videos/Demo%20Slam/Google%20Demo%20Slam_%20Extra%20Spicy/bg.jpg

The code above can fetch this resource without any problems both when running on the Nexus Player, and in the Emulator. 
But it seems as though I cannot fetch resources from other domains than the googleapis.com domain.

I have checked and updated all Android tools to the latest versions. Including platform tools and system images.

I have also tried deleting all AVDs I had that might be outdated and created new ones - but no success.

I am starting the AVD with the "-dns-server 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4" argument so that it should be able to do DNS lookups.

I might be mistaken, but it seems like the googleapis.com addresses have been whitelisted in the emulator somehow.
Is there some place or setting where I can whitelist my own URL, or similar way that I can get access to my api on the internet when running in the emulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to update this.

It turned out to be a bug in the Android Emulator. Google fixed it about 6 months after the issue was reported. Or I guess they fixed it earlier than that, but it was not released to the public until 6 months later.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the proxy on emulator settings. Another common issue: check the date/time of emulator. If old, then SSL will not work.

Comment: Sorry - I forgot to close this issue. It was a bug in the android emulator. Google fixed about 6 months after I reported it. By then I had more or less given up developing for AndroidTV using the emulator.